# How to iterate over pandas.Timestamp?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd

start_date = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-15')
end_date = pd.Timestamp('2017-02-15')
```

How can I print dates from `2017-01-15` through `2017-02-15`?

I mean I want to print something like this:

```
2017-01-15
2017-01-16
2017-01-17
2017-01-18
...
2017-02-13
2017-02-14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with subtract 1 day:

```
d = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))
```

Or change `end Timestamp`:

```
start_date = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-15')
end_date = pd.Timestamp('2017-02-14')

d = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)
```

Or parameter `closed='left'`, thank you @Jon Clements:

```
d = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, closed='left')
```

---

```
print (d)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-15', '2017-01-16', '2017-01-17', '2017-01-18',
               '2017-01-19', '2017-01-20', '2017-01-21', '2017-01-22',
               '2017-01-23', '2017-01-24', '2017-01-25', '2017-01-26',
               '2017-01-27', '2017-01-28', '2017-01-29', '2017-01-30',
               '2017-01-31', '2017-02-01', '2017-02-02', '2017-02-03',
               '2017-02-04', '2017-02-05', '2017-02-06', '2017-02-07',
               '2017-02-08', '2017-02-09', '2017-02-10', '2017-02-11',
               '2017-02-12', '2017-02-13', '2017-02-14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

---

And for loop:

```
for dates in d:
    print (dates)
```

Comment: Or used `closed=left` with the original values... eg: `pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, closed='left')`

Comment: ...and the best thing about using `close=` is that it works with `freq=` nicely, so you don't have to amend your end date to either be 1) the inclusive end point of that frequency or 2) repeat the frequency in a Timedelta and take that off... eg: `pd.date_range(start_end, end_date, freq='H', close='left')` is fairly clear as to what it's doing versus... `end_date = '2017-02-14 23:00:00'` or doing `end_date - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='H')`... it's possible to get one of those wrong (eg: maybe miss off the hour unit from the delta or typo the first etc...). (In short... I'd avoid the first two!)